# Multiple regression with OLS in python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, statsmodels

I have a code for multiple OLS-regression with the Newey-West procedure.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,5,7,4,5,6,4,7,8,9],
                   'b':[3,5,6,2,4,6,7,8,7,8,9]})

results = sm.OLS(df.a, sm.add_constant(df.b)).fit()
new = results.get_robustcov_results(cov_type='HAC',maxlags=1)
print new.summary()
```

It works, but how should I change the code, if I have more variables like....

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,5,7,4,5,6,4,7,8,9],
                   'b':[3,5,6,2,4,6,7,8,7,8,9],
                   'c':[3,5,6,2,4,8,7,8,9,9,9],
                   'd':[3,5,6,2,5,8,8,9,8,10,9]})
```

... and wanted to analyse their influence on variable a, like the analysis of variable b in the original code?

How should the Code-line `results = sm.OLS(df.a, sm.add_constant(df.b)).fit()` looks like?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can supply multiple variables like this:

```
results = sm.OLS(df.a, sm.add_constant(df[list('bcd')])).fit()
```